# SWIFTUI Change data on received JSON that has some items in String and change them to Double

Tags: ios, arrays, json, xcode, swiftui

I'm receiving JSON data in this format:

```
struct OfficesLocationModel: Codable{
var Items : [offices] = [] }

struct offices: Codable, Identifiable {
var id : Int = 0
var City : String = ""
var Longitude : String = ""
var Latitude : String = ""
var Name : String = "" }
```

But I need latitude and longitude in Double in order to list offices location on a map view

How can I convert o cast those in the data type needed?

I've tried to convert them to double in many ways but nothing works, any help is very appreciated

Comment: show us what you have tried, in case you haven't tried this: `Double("45.6789")`

Comment: Yes it worked doing that, the problem was in the MapAnnotation structure. Thank you very much